# How to read table

Tags: r, text-mining

I have a .txt file and I am required to read the bottom table using **read.table()**

http://pages.stat.wisc.edu/~jgillett/327-1/4/beef.txt

How could I clean the text to do that?

Answer (score 1):

The "comment.char" parameters in read.table() allows you to skip those lines with comments.

```
> A <- read.table('beef.txt', header = T, comment.char = "%")
> str(A)
'data.frame':   17 obs. of  10 variables:
$ YEAR : int  1925 1926 1927 1928 1929 1930 1931 1932 1933 1934 ...
$ PBE  : num  59.7 59.7 63 71 71 74.2 72.1 79 73.1 70.2 ...
$ CBE  : num  58.6 59.4 53.7 48.1 49 48.2 47.9 46 50.8 55.2 ...
$ PPO  : num  60.5 63.3 59.9 56.3 55 59.6 57 49.5 47.3 56.6 ...
$ CPO  : num  65.8 63.3 66.8 69.9 68.7 66.1 67.4 69.7 68.7 62.2 ...
$ PFO  : num  65.8 68 65.5 64.8 65.6 62.4 51.4 42.8 41.6 46.4 ...
$ DINC : num  51.4 52.6 52.1 52.7 55.1 48.8 41.5 31.4 29.4 33.2 ...
$ CFO  : num  90.9 92.1 90.9 90.9 91.1 90.7 90 87.8 88 89.1 ...
$ RDINC: num  68.5 69.6 70.2 71.9 75.2 68.3 64 53.9 53.2 58 ...
$ RFP  : int  877 899 883 884 895 874 791 733 752 811 ...
```